# Camera Tracking - Fast camera move

Tags: camera, tracking

Fairly new to camera tracking. I did a camera move that goes from the ceiling to the floor and I'm not able to get a camera solve to work. Camera trackers only last so long as when the camera moves they are out of frame.

Not sure if there's a different method when you have fast big camera moves?

[image]

Comment: Good camera tracking relies on markers being present and clear for most the video, so quick or large moves are generally difficult (but not impossible). If you can share your Blend file and any associated footage we may be able to better help you https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sure thing please take a look.
https://we.tl/t-m1bKlWHdKA

Answer (score 0):

Creating a good camera track relies on several factors that allow Blender to calculate the three dimensional movement of the camera. These suggestions below can help you improve your motion tracking.

- A variety of conspicuous track points present in all three dimensions of the scene, meaning left-right and up-down, but also having trackers in the foreground and background of your footage.
- A majority of these trackers need to stay in frame. It is fine if some go out of frame once in a while, but you'll need to go in and manually make adjustments/delete certain trackers if they get lost.
- Stable/clear footage is always easier. It is possible to track footage that has large or quick movements, but it will require more work and more trackers. Any movement that may confuse Blender as to how the camera is moving may cause a track solver to fail.
- You can also play around with using actual tracking markers like [these](https://www.shutterstock.com/shutterstock/photos/1708584424/display_1500/stock-vector-vfx-motion-marker-set-video-footage-replacement-tracking-markers-element-1708584424.jpg). I will often print out some and place them around my scene before recording footage. This will help Blender better stay locked on the track points so you will probably get a better track; however, you will need to do some more work in post to remove them from the scene.
- Make sure that the scene has good lighting and use as high of a frame rate as possible to reduce the effects of motion blur.
- If you need really fast movements but Blender is having trouble solving a camera track, then try recording your scene at half or a quarter of the speed that you want it (physically move the camera slower). This will reduce motion blur and give Blender more footage to work with, and you can always then speed the clip back up later.

The footage of the table and chairs that you attached seems very trackable to me, so I'd recommend playing around with some of the techniques above and see what works best.

Comment: So sorry i attached the wrong video clip associated with my blend file. This is the shot I'm having issue with. https://we.tl/t-j79hJa0ebq

Comment: This footage definitely looks harder to track, but I don't think it's impossible. If possible, I might reshoot the footage with some clear tracking markers in frame (whether true trackers or just clearly defined objects) because you loose a lot of key features near the end when the camera is pointed at the ground and there are no good points from which to track. It won't be easy, but I think its possible if you put some time into it!